# Prime spectrums bijection but not homeomorphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $f$ be a homomorphism from commutative ring $A$ to $B$.  Suppose $f$ induces a bijection between $\operatorname{Spec} B$ and $\operatorname{Spec} A$.  Must $\operatorname{Spec} A$ and $\operatorname{Spec} B$ be homeomorphic?  Are there any counterexamples？(The topology is Zariski topology)